# What is the best way to delete all contacts on the handset?

Tags: contacts

I was trying to clean up the contacts on my Droid X and part of the process (after turning off sync) was to delete all contacts on the phone.  I didn't have many, so I manually deleted each on (read: tedious).  Is there a way to bulk delete contacts on a handset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the home screen hit the menu button and go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications. Make sure yo are in the "All Applications" tab so you see the system apps and choose "Contact Storage" and click "Clear Data".  **This will delete all your contacts without disturbing anything else.**

Comment: I know what you mean @Matt.  Some members of this SE site seem to have a poor idea of what a downvote should mean (I have gotten more than one downvote for an acceptable answer, all without a comment to explain what the problem is).

Comment: Nobody needs to validate their vote. In fact, it has been seen that people who *do* comment when they downvote are often attacked for it. I suppose downvotes are just more noticeable here because we're a fraction of the size of Stack Overflow or Super User.

Comment: (but this is a meta conversation, so it shouldn't be continued here)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this file if you have root: `data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db`

You could also try clearing data for Contacts Storage (`Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`).

Finally a factory reset will do this, but you lose all your user apps and data as well.

Note: As per Ryan's comment, you'll need to shut off contact sync for your accounts if you don't want the contacts to be repopulated.

Comment: If you have sync setup, won't the contacts resync?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the question, but I think he's just trying to clear everything off the phone so he can do a fresh sync.  So that should be OK.  But a valid point; I'll add a caveat to my answer.

Comment: I think that you have it @matthew-read (I mention turning off sync above).  The goal of the exercise is to get a fresh sync

Comment: read: Have you tried the second method? It does not delete any contacts for me.

Comment: @Matt I forgot that Contacts had a separate Contacts Storage.  +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this app, imaginatively entitled [Delete Contacts](http://market.android.com/details?id=in.umobile.delall)

[image: QR code for "Delete Contacts" app]

Interestingly, doesn't work on the Droid. There are also, of course, some other apps in the "Related" area that would appear to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My phone is rooted. First I made sure all of my data was correct at www.google.com/contacts . Then exported the data (.csv file) from google’s web site to my home computer for safe storage. I used the app Titanium Backup to “Wipe data” for the apps Contacts 4.0.3 and Contacts Storage 4.0.3. Next, waited (approx 1 min) for my phone to re-sync with google and all of the contacts were restored. Finally, I went back into Titanium Backup and preformed a full back up for apps Contacts 4.0.3 and Contacts Storage 4.0.3.